# How to implement a download queue and active connections management?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app where for each screen need to be loaded some images (could be even 50) and some JSON from a REST API. The problem is that the user can change screens before all images have loaded and they keep downloading when the new screen shows up, which is bad.

**My end goal is to be able to cancel all active downloads when the screen changes. Even if the image has not finished downloading.** 

Having a queue to download no more than 5 images at the same time would be nice too.
Here is how I'm downloading images right now:

```
// global queue
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.data objectForKey:@"image_url"]]];
self.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[DataManager sharedManager] storeImageData:self.image forImageWithID:self.imageID];
    [self.delegate downloadedImage:self];
});
```

Comment: Switch to use `NSOperation` for your data downloading, one option could be to start using [AFnetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). You should never use initWithURL options since it will not give you enough control over what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use operation queues instead of GCD. This way you can constrain it to five concurrent requests at a time and they're cancelable. You should also use `NSURLConnection` instead of `dataWithContentsOfURL`, so that you can cancel it while the download is in progress.

Putting a `NSURLConnection` inside a `NSOperation` can be tricky, though (because you have to schedule it in a runloop). Probably easiest is to just avail yourself of a third party class, such as [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

If you add your operations to your own queue, just set its [`maxConcurrentOperationCount`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004592-RH2-borderType) to be `5`, and if you want to cancel the operations, you can just call [`cancelAllOperations`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004592-RH2-SW9).

---

Depending on how you're using the images, you might contemplate not loading the images in an array at all. For example, if you're just populating the images in `UIImageView` objects, consider using a `UIImageView` category, such as AFNetworking's [`UIImageView+AFNetworking`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.1/Categories/UIImageView+AFNetworking.html) category:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i.imgur.com/r4uwx.jpg"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder-avatar"]];
```

Or you can use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) which offers a slightly richer `UIImageView` category. It offers its own `UIImageView` methods called [`setImageWithURL`](http://hackemist.com/SDWebImage/doc/Categories/UIImageView%28WebCache%29.html#//api/name/setImageWithURL%3a).

But if you use a `UIImageView` category, you can employ "lazy loading", only loading the image when you create the image view. This is ideal for user interfaces such as `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`.

Comment: I looked at AFNetworking, seems like I will try it out. But how do I cancel ALL active connections with that framework? Which was my question. I didn't see such info in the readme.

Comment: If you add your operations to your own queue, you can then then do the standard `NSOperationQueue` method, [`cancelAllOperations`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004592-RH2-SW9). Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: Can I do that using the AFNetworking framework, or I must implement my own NSOperationQueue, subclass NSOperation, etc.?

Comment: @NikolayDyankov AFNetworking creates objects subclassed from `NSOperation`. So you can just add them to a `NSOperationQueue` you create and configure. You can also use the framework's `AFHTTPClient`, which creates an operation queue for you.

Comment: So far so good, but I need to be able to cancel images that are being downloaded. Having to wait for all 5 images in the queue to download somewhat kills the point of having this queue. And it can be a pretty long wait on a 3G connection.

Comment: @NikolayDyankov Very good. If we have any other discussion, we should move [this discussion to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37949/discussion-between-rob-and-nikolay-dyankov). I'm going to remove some of my comments here, but they're out there in that chat.

Comment: It works! The app is dramatically faster now, thanks for the help!